# Override an asset host in rails, via the helper methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, assets, content-delivery-network

I was wondering if there was a way to override the asset host of an image.

For example lets say I have the following asset host and image tag

```
config.asset_host = "www.xxx.com
image_tag "blerg.gif"
```

This would out put and image tag with the scr:

```
www.xxx.com/blerg.gif
```

Is there a way to change the asset host inline for example:

```
image_tag "blerg.gif", :host => 'www.yyy.com
```

Which would change the asset host of the image.

Cheers.

Comment: you can pass your full url like `image_tag "http://www.yyy.com/blerg.gif"`

Comment: Yeah it just works, answer it and I'll give you a point :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass your full url: `image_tag "http://www.yyy.com/blerg.gif"`